# Entering user input in .txt file

Tags: java

I am new to Java and don't know much about it. I created a java code that takes user input. I have created a Submit button in my program. I want that the program should store user input in a .txt file in my hard drive. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class myfirstapp extends JFrame {


public JButton submit;
public JTextField field1;
public JTextField field2;
public JTextField field3;
public JLabel label;
public JPasswordField passwordfield;

public void myfirstapp(){

    field1 = new JTextField("Enter your Email Id:");
    field1.setEditable(false);
    add(field1);

    field2 = new JTextField(20);
    add(field2);

    field3 = new JTextField("Enter your password below:");
    field3.setEditable(false);
    add(field3);

    label = new JLabel("Exclusive production of PCIT");
    add(label,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    passwordfield = new JPasswordField(20);
    add(passwordfield);

    submit = new JButton("Get Likes!");
    submit.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    public Formatter x;
                    private void openFile(){

                        try{
                        x = new Formatter("D:\\gta.txt");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("You got an error");
                    }


                }

                public void addRecords(){
                    x.submit();
                }
                public void closeFile(){
                    x.close();
                    }
                }

            );
    add(submit);


}}
```

I am getting error on this line:

```
private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
```

The error says: Syntax error on tokens(s),misplaced constructor(s).
What should i do? I don't know how to handle this situation.Kindly help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are having method within a method
- You need to implement the `actionPerformed` method of `ActionListener`, and while implementing you cannot decrease the visibility of the method. Make it `public actionPerformed`

Correct approach

```
    submit.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                //x should be a field since its accessed within other methods
                public Formatter x;

                //this method should be public
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                }

                //open file should be a different method and remove it from actionPerformed
                private void openFile(){
                    try{
                        x = new Formatter("D:\\gta.txt");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("You got an error");
                    }


                }

                public void addRecords(){
                    x.submit();
                }
                public void closeFile(){
                    x.close();
                }
            }

            );
```